# In Liferay, how can I change the site template associated to a site

Tags: liferay-6

I have a site that is currently based on a site template. I would like to delete all pages in this site (keeping the content), and link the site to a new site template.

The [Jira issue LPS-33179](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-33179) asks precisely that question from a GUI perspective. I would like to know from a coder's perspective.

I am using Liferay 6.1.0 GA2.

Thanks,
Alain

Comment: you can use `SitesUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypesLinks`. If you are to do this with portlet then you have to copy all the code for this methods in your portlet

Comment: Thanks, Pankaj. I think I found a solution from different sources (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I used, and it seems to work :

```
LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled
```

to set the link to the prototype, and

```
SitesUtil.mergeLayoutSetProtypeLayouts
```

to update the sites immediately. The latter is called using PortalClassInvoker based on [code from Jelmer Kuperus](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/10488983#_19_message_10488983)

```
public static void setupSitesFromSiteTemplate(long groupId, long publicSiteTemplateId,
                                              long privateSiteTemplateId) throws PortalException, SystemException {
    Group group = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(groupId);
    if (publicSiteTemplateId != 0) setSiteTemplate(group, publicSiteTemplateId, false);
    if (privateSiteTemplateId != 0) setSiteTemplate(group, privateSiteTemplateId, true);
}

public static void setSiteTemplate(Group group, long siteTemplateId, boolean isPrivateLayout)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {
    long groupId = group.getGroupId();
    LayoutSetPrototype prototype = LayoutSetPrototypeLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSetPrototype(siteTemplateId);
    boolean layoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled = true;
    LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(groupId, isPrivateLayout,
            layoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled, prototype.getUuid());
    try {
        LayoutSet layoutSet = LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.getLayoutSet(groupId, isPrivateLayout);
        mergeLayoutSetProtypeLayouts(group, layoutSet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (_log.isWarnEnabled()) {
            String privatePublic = isPrivateLayout ? "private" : "public";
            _log.warn(String.format("Could not merge %s layouts for group[%d] from template[%d]", privatePublic,
                    groupId, siteTemplateId));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void mergeLayoutSetProtypeLayouts(Group group, LayoutSet layoutSet) throws Exception {

    MethodKey key = SitesUtilMethodKey("mergeLayoutSetProtypeLayouts", Group.class, LayoutSet.class);
    invokePortalClassMethod(key, group, layoutSet);
}
/*
 * copied from
 * http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message /10488983#_19_message_10488983 
 * post by Jelmer Kuperus
 *
 * key: key of method to be called, e.g. com.liferay.portlet.sites.util.SitesUtil
 * arguments:  arguments to be passed to the invoked method
 * returns: result of the invoked method
 */
private static Object invokePortalClassMethod(MethodKey key, Object... arguments) throws PortalException {
    try {
        // noinspection unchecked
        return PortalClassInvoker.invoke(false, key, arguments);
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
private static final String SITES_UTIL_CLASS_NAME = "com.liferay.portlet.sites.util.SitesUtil";
private static MethodKey SitesUtilMethodKey(String methodName, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
    return new MethodKey(SITES_UTIL_CLASS_NAME, methodName, parameterTypes);
}
```

Comment: The typo on the method mergeLayoutSetProtypeLayouts has been corrected in Liferay 6.1.2 GA3. The misspelled method still works but is deprecated.